# Flex / AS3 Debugger or Profiler

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

In the past I have used **[Red Gate ANTS Memory Profiler](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)** for .NET debugging, in particular I have used it to find memory being held by event listeners. The software allows the developer to see which objects currently exist and if they are marked for GC, it even shows a tree of the objects.

I now face this exact same problem (event handlers and garbage collection) in flex and need to find a similar tool that can do the same for AS3.

Are there any similar tools available? I have seen the profiler built into Flash Builder, but this doesn't really help much.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't help much? Are you taking snapshots and looking for loitering objects?

Comment: Flash Develop comes with a debugger that shows the live object counts you might want to take a look at that.

Comment: adobe Scout might be an option

Comment: The Flash Builder profiler isn't the most intuitive tool but it's quite capable.  I found [this](http://tikalk.com/flex/solving-memory-leaks-using-flash-builder-4-profiler) to be pretty helpful.

Comment: You should look into Adobe Scout. It's a profiler that allows you to view pretty much everything (though not objects marked for GC). As far as I am aware, there is no better profiler out there and nothing else even comes close to what you want.

Comment: @LeeBurrows, thanks for the scout suggestion, way better than the built in profiler

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3: Thanks, I'm using scout now and it's solved my problem. Although it doesn't show objects marked for GC, it does show when GC occurs which was helpful

Comment: Yeah, you can find a ton of stuff in there if you really go digging. There's a lot hidden. I do wish it showed objects marked for GC, though. Would really help pinpoint memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - The Miner. It has a lot of options and you can call the GC manually...

http://www.sociodox.com/theminer/